# Write nested defaultdict to csv

Tags: python, csv, nested, defaultdict

I have a nested defaultdict:

```
data_dict = 
{
    "5uz7_R": {
        "section1": {
            "=": 0,
            "-": 0,
            ".": 24,
            "+": 30,
            "|": 4,
            "gaps": 1,
            "score": 0
        },
        "section2": {
            "=": 0,
            "-": 0,
            ".": 35,
            "+": 31,
            "|": 5,
            "gaps": 1,
            "score": 0
        }
    },
    "4l6r_A": {
        "section1": {
            "=": 0,
            "-": 0,
            ".": 23,
            "+": 32,
            "|": 3,
            "gaps": 1,
            "score": 0
        },
        "section2": {
            "=": 0,
            "-": 0,
            ".": 32,
            "+": 32,
            "|": 5,
            "gaps": 3,
            "score": 0
        }
    }
}
```

that I want to write to a csv (or tab-delimited) file that would look like this:

```
        section1                            section2                        
        =   -   .   +   |   gaps    score   =   -   .   +   |   gaps    score
5uz7_R  0   0   24  30  4   1       0       0   0   35  31  5   1       0
4l6r_A  0   0   23  32  3   1       0       0   0   32  32  5   3       0
```

csv.DictWriter seems to be perfect for this (please don't suggest using pandas :D), I just can't figure out how to do it correctly in this particular case.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting what I wanted with a few for loops, .write() statements and explicitly writing many '\t' and '\n', but I was hoping to use something less clunky than this:

```
out.write('SEP=\t'+'\n'+'\t')
for section in section_list:
    out.write(section+'\t'*(len(symbol_list)))
out.write('\n'+'\t')
for section in section_list:
    for symbol in symbol_list:
        out.write(symbol+'\t')
out.write('\n')
for pdb in pdb_list:
    out.write(pdb+'\t')
    for section in section_list:
        for symbol in symbol_list:
            out.write(str(data_dict[pdb][section][symbol])+'\t')
    out.write('\n')
```